# Multi-layered favicon with GraphicsMagik

Tags: graphicsmagick

I can see its possible to use ImageMagik to create a multilayered favicon but as we've just switched to GraphicsMagik I need to do it with that instead.

You can see the ImageMagik code here: http://blog.lavoie.sl/2012/11/multi-resolution-favicon-using-imagemagick.html

I've not been able to find some documentation on how to do a multilayered .ico with GraphicsMagik, so maybe someone in here have the required knowledge?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?